# R using RNetLogo package error regarding "store the NetLogo instance is already in use"

Tags: r, netlogo, rjava

I am new to Stackoverflow and the `RNetLogo` package so any help would be very much appreciated as I have looked through the internet for the solution the last 2 days.

I have been using the RNetlogo package and have not had any problems until yesterday.

Now I am getting the error-

> "Error in NLStart(model.path) : 
>     Name of object (nl.obj) to store the NetLogo instance
>         is already in use. Please quit the used object first or choose a different name."

I have tried the `NLQuit(all=True)`

but then it tells me that I cannot change the working directory.

I have uninstalled and reinstalled R and NetLogo and have checked that I have admin permission to the C drive, and R and NetLogo are both in "C:/Program Files"

```
>getwd()
#[1] "C:/Program Files/NetLogo 5.2.0
```

For a couple of days I have had some trouble with `RStudio` not shutting down so I am wondering if it did not execute the `NLQuit()` function properly and so now thinks that it is still running?

I'm not sure if this may be a Java issue??

Any help would be much appreciated
Thank you!!

Comment: Do you see anything if you type `RNetLogo:::.rnetlogo$objects` ?

Comment: Thank you, I have tried nl.obj=NULL in both the NLStart and NLLoad Model commands and it seems happy but now it will run NLCommand but will not return any reports, the error is now " Error in .jcall(nl.obj, "Ljava/lang/Object;", "report", .jnew("java/lang/String",  : 
  Expected a constant. at position 57 in ", this perhaps looks like a Java issue do you think?  Thank you for your help

Comment: Looks like you are now successfully talking to NetLogo but the command syntax is wrong. "Expected a constant. at position... " is typical NetLogo error (maybe you are creating a list of non-constant variables with []). Try the command in NetLogo console first (as observer).

Comment: And as  you mention reports... `NLComnmand` executes a command in NetLogo (run procedures, set variables or similar). If you want to read something from NetLogo with reporter syntax use `NLReport`.

Comment: Thank you for this- Yes sorry I should have said this all worked last week but I started geeting these errors but had not updated anything on the computer. so the syntax works in Netlogo e.g.

Comment: _(in NetLogo)_ observer> `show [ meanDistance_m ] of patchstatistics`  _(in R)_ `NLGetAgentSet ( "[ meanDistance_m ]", "patchstatistics")`. What is different this time is that when I use _(in R)_ `NLCommand("setup")`, I get the report from the command centre of NetLogo in R without asking for it! e.g. (patch 46 209): 0.

Comment: It is hard to say anything without NetLogo source code. patchstatistics is turtle breed and meanDistance_m is variable owned by this breed? If I can guess - you don't need the brackets around agents vars when using NLGetAgentSet.

Comment: Yes this works, thank you! Your help is much appreciated